# What members of the Darkmagic family has the adventurers of Acquisitions, Inc met?

Tags: penny-arcade, acquisitions-inc

Outside of Jim, who else from the Darkmagic family has been mentioned in the adventures of Acquisitions, Inc.?  Be in it passing conversation, or direct contact/interaction.

Comment: Jim's Magic Missile©

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the start of the YouTube series proper, the PA guys several Acquisitions, Inc. did live sessions at PAX. In 2011, the session was ["The Last Will and Testament of Jim Darkmagic"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzIJemFtXXs), which sees the party visit Jim's family for the reading of his father's will.

We meet several members of the Darkmagic family, including:

- Olivia and Percival, Jim's sister and brother (raised as cousins)
- Wretched and Hideous, Jim's cousins
- Martha, Jim's mother
- Wanda, Jim's aunt (who raised Olivia and Percival)
- Gorgon, Jim's aunt (Wretched and Hideous's mother)
- Delores, Jim's grandmother

We also hear about Jim's father James II. Presumably his grandfather (Delores's husband) was also James.